# Form validation using glyph-icon click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to do form validation using JavaScript. I am using a pencil icon as my edit button and a floppy disc icon as my save icon.

Here i am doing color change of the text box when text box is empty with the color red so when text box is filled up with text it should turn to grey. I had written code for that but problem is when text box is empty its turning to red but when text box is filled up with text its not turning to grey.

```html
<script>
$(document)
    .ready(
        function() {
            $('.editAddBtn')
                .click(
                    function() {
                        if ($('.editField').is(
                                '[readonly]')) { //checks if it is already on readonly mode
                            $('.editField').prop(
                                'readonly', false); //turns the readonly off
                            $('.editAddBtn')
                                .html(
                                    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk">&nbsp;</span>'); //Changes the text of the button

                        } else { //else we do other things


                            var cstreet_1 = document.getElementById('currentAddressLine1').value

                            if (cstreet_1 == "") {
                                document.getElementById('currentAddressLine1').style.borderColor = "red";
                                return false;
                            } else {
                                document.getElementById('currentAddressLine1').style.borderColor = "grey";


                            }

                            $('.editField').prop(
                                'readonly', true);
                            $('.editAddBtn')
                                .html(
                                    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">&nbsp;</span>');



                        }

                        if ($('.mySelect').is(
                                '[disabled]')) {
                            $('.mySelect').prop(
                                'disabled', false);
                            $('#chk').prop('disabled',
                                false);
                        } else {
                            $('.mySelect').prop(
                                'disabled', true);
                            $('#chk').prop('disabled',
                                false);
                        }
                    });

        });

</script>
```

Comment: Could you please post the accompanying HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine.

```html
<script>
  $(document)
    .ready(
      function() {
        $('.editAddBtn')
          .click(
            function() {
              if ($('.editField').is(
                  '[readonly]')) { //checks if it is already on readonly mode
                $('.editField').prop(
                  'readonly', false); //turns the readonly off
                $('.editAddBtn')
                  .html(
                    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk">&nbsp;</span>'); //Changes the text of the button

              } else { //else we do other things


                var cstreet_1 = document.getElementById('currentAddressLine1').value

                if (cstreet_1 == "") {
                  document.getElementById('currentAddressLine1').style.borderColor = "red";
                  return false;
                } else {
                  document.getElementById('currentAddressLine1').style.borderColor = "grey";


                }

                $('.editField').prop(
                  'readonly', true);
                $('.editAddBtn')
                  .html(
                    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">&nbsp;</span>');



              }

              if ($('.mySelect').is(
                  '[disabled]')) {
                $('.mySelect').prop(
                  'disabled', false);
                $('#chk').prop('disabled',
                  false);
              } else {
                $('.mySelect').prop(
                  'disabled', true);
                $('#chk').prop('disabled',
                  false);
              }
            });

      });
</script>
```